# custom django sub-admin custom permission provided by admin

Tags: python, django, admin

I have a django custom django admin panel and now i have create a new app where admin will be able to register sub admin

once subadmin is registered he will get into another app where he has to select the sub admin from the drop down and will see the different app name with two option read or rea/write admin has to select one and that specific app with that select permission will be allocated the subadmin

Pleas let me know how i can achieve this

Comment: This is also described in the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset